# Generic class, can't return generic value

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to deserialize a time string to a Joda DateTime, so I defined this deserializer:

```
public class JsonTimeDeserializer<T extends DateTime> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
        return json == null ? null : dtf.parseDateTime(json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
required: T
Found org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I don't understand. T extends DateTime.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that `T == DateTime` given that literally a line above you declared that `T extends DateTime`. In fact, why is this even generic?

Comment: okay yes. I see your point

Answer (score 2):

Your first line should read

```
public class JsonTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DateTime>
```

You don't need to create your own variable, just reference the existing one

When you extend a generic type and add a new type variable, you are making your type generic as well, which is not what you want in this case.